# Compile and run rust programs without creating separate cargo projects

Tags: rust

While going through [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/),
I found myself creating a new cargo project for each program in the tutorial.

This quickly turned cumbersome.

Another strategy I tried was having my working directory structured like this:

```
src\
    guessing_game.rs
    main.rs
    temp.rs
```

where `main.rs` contains

```rust
mod guessing_game;
mod temp;

/// Hello
fn main() {
    // guessing_game::play();
    println!("{}", temp::is_prime(6));
}
```

and `cargo.toml` contains

```rust
[package]
name = "rust_prog_dump"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.4"
```

I would call the target function in `main()` and comment out the others.

Do we have an alternative?

I have seen [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/9826) and [Jon Cairns' post](http://joncairns.com/2015/10/a-single-command-to-compile-and-run-rust-programs/).
I use Windows, hence that script does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do we have an alternative?

One alternative is to compile by hand using `rustc` directly, however that is annoying if you want dependencies.

An other alternative is to have multiple binaries in the crate, then you can select the binary to compile (and run) using `--bin`:

```bash
> cargo new multibin
     Created binary (application) `multibin` package
> cd multibin
> mkdir src/bin
> echo 'fn main() { println!("test 1"); }' > src/bin/test1.rs
> echo 'fn main() { println!("test 2"); }' > src/bin/test2.rs
> echo 'fn main() { println!("primary"); }' >| src/main.rs
> cargo r
error: `cargo run` could not determine which binary to run. Use the `--bin` option to specify a binary, or the `default-run` manifest key.
available binaries: multibin, test1, test2
> cargo r --bin multibin
   Compiling multibin v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/multibin)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.44s
     Running `target/debug/multibin`
primary
> cargo r --bin test1
   Compiling multibin v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/multibin)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.10s
     Running `target/debug/test1`
test 1
> cargo r --bin test2
   Compiling multibin v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/multibin)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.10s
     Running `target/debug/test2`
test 2
```

As you can see you can have a `src/main.rs` which will inherit the crate's name, but usually if you start having multiple binaries you put them all in `src/bin`.

A third alternative is to use something like [`cargo-script`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-script) (by far the most convenient but long unmaintained and IIRC only compatible with edition 2015) or [`runner`](https://crates.io/crates/runner) or something along those lines (there are probably others).